# min-height not allowing full height child

Tags: html, css

I Have a div with the following css class (generated)

```
min-height: {
    margin-top: 30px !important;
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px) !important;
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 60px) !important;
    min-height: calc(100% - 60px) !important;
}
```

when I add a div inside with a height of 100% the content doesn't fill to the parent div - only when the parent div has the height attribute set not the min-height.

How can i make the  child div expand to the full size of the parent div if it only has min-height set?

```
<div class="min-height">
    <div class="full-height">not much content<div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a height on something like that, it's parent needs to have a height specified, and so on up the chain.

(Also you have a lot of syntax errors in your CSS)

For example. Add a height to the HTML and Body elements. Also give the parent a height.  Now your child, can have 100% height of it's container.

```css
body, html {
 height: 100%;
}

.min-height {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
    background: gray;
    padding: 10px;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="min-height">
    <div class="full-height">not much content<div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The min-height class should also have a height. Then add the following rules for the full-height class:

```css
.full-height {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```